# How to intercept or edit curried function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm new to js and functional programing

my question is below

```
const orgFunc = (str, str2) =>{
    return str + ' ' + str2;
}

const curryFunc = (str) =>
{
    return orgFunc(str,'curried'); 
}

const interceptFunc = (fn) =>
{
    return fn;
}

1 console.log("orgFunc",orgFunc('func','org'));
>func org
2 console.log("curryFunc", curryFunc('func'));
>func curried    
3 console.log("interceptFunc", interceptFunc(curryFunc)('func'));
>func curried
```

I want to change 3's result "func curried" to "func intercepted"
with replacement "curried" to "intercepted"

but in interceptFunc function,

```
const interceptFunc = (fn) =>
{
    return fn
}
```

fn is function so I can't use fn.replace("curried","intercepted")

Is there any way?

Comment: curried functions are pure functions.. i.e for an input it should return always the same output. From what you have asked it seems that at upon some condition you want to return a different output. To return a different output, I suggest you simply make another curried function.

Comment: If you want to intercept the argument that `curryFunc` passes to `orgFunc`, then `interceptFunc(curryFunc)` will not be able to do that.

Comment: It's really unclear what currying has to do with your code, you are not using it anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by modifying your `interceptFunc` function.

Your `interceptFunc` is not doing anything other than just returning another function.

Check the below code snippet in which we return another function which actually acts as an interceptor.

```js
const orgFunc = (str, str2) =>{
    return str + ' ' + str2;
}

const curryFunc = (str) =>
{
    return orgFunc(str,'curried'); 
}

const interceptFunc = (fn) =>
{
    return function(someInput){
      return fn(someInput).replace('curried', 'intercepted'); 
    }
}

console.log(interceptFunc(curryFunc)("func"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure  what you  want to do. But  you can use replace like that:

```js
const orgFunc = (str, str2) =>{
    return str + ' ' + str2;
}

const curryFunc = (str) =>
{
    return orgFunc(str,'curried'); 
}

const interceptFunc = (fn) =>
{
    return fn;
}

console.log("orgFunc",orgFunc('func','org'));

console.log("curryFunc", curryFunc('func'));
 
console.log("interceptFunc", interceptFunc(curryFunc)('func').replace('curried', 'intercepted'));
```